# Check date and edit adjacent cell in Google Sheet with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script that will change the status (Current vs Expired) in an adjacent cell when looping over the cell values of a column containing dates if the date is equal to or less than today's date. The script needs to work on column N (dates) and modify column O (statuses) across ALL sheets in the spreadsheet. That is why I have the Sheets loop in there FYI.

Here is what I have so far and I just keep hitting walls.

It's currently throwing an error at the currentValue variable for being out of range.

```
//----------------------------------------------------

// Look at Dates and Change Status if expired (Automatically)
function checkDates() {
 //For each sheet in the Spreadsheet
 for(v in sheets){  
 //Find the last row that has content *-2 is because of a strange return I don't understand yet
 var lastRow = sheets[v].getLastRow()-2;
 //Get Dates Range (excluding empty cells)
 var dateRange = sheets[v].getRange("N2:N"+lastRow);
 //Get the number of Rows in the range
 var numRows = dateRange.getNumRows();

  //For loop for the number of rows with content
  for(x = 0; x <= numRows; ++x){
    // Value of cell in loop
    var currentValue = dateRange.getCell(x,2).getValue();
    Logger.log(currentValue);
    // Row number in Range
    var currentRow = dateRange.getRow(x);
    // Get adjacent cell Range
    var adjacentCell = sheets[v].getRange(currentRow,15);
    // If the date is less than or equal to today
    if(new Date(currentValue) <= d){
    // Change adjancet cell to Expired
    adjacentCell.setValue("Expired");
    // Else adjance cell is Current
    } else if(listofDates != ""){
    adjacentCell.setValue("Current");
    }
  }
 } 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for currentValue to be out of range is that the `getCell(x, 2)` function first parameter is the row number. Your row number starts at 0, `x = 0`. If you change x to start at 1 it should stop giving you the error that the currentValue variable is out of range.

```
for(x = 1; x <= numRows; ++x){ ...
```

You are also selecting 2 columns across but you only selected out of row "N", change `getCell(x, 2)` to `getCell(x, 1)`.

```
var currentValue = dateRange.getCell(x,1).getValue();
```

As I mentioned before your data range is only over colmn "N", it can make it easier if you select both column "N" and "O", `var dateRange = sheets[v].getRange("N2:O");`
I modified the rest of your script a bit. It is not pretty but I do hope it helps you.

```
function checkDates() {
 //For each sheet in the Spreadsheet

  for(v in sheets){  
    var lastRow = sheets[v].getLastRow();
    //Get Dates Range (excluding empty cells)
    var dateRange = sheets[v].getRange(2, 14, (lastRow - 1), 2);
    //Get the number of Rows in the range
    var numRows = dateRange.getNumRows();

    //For loop for the number of rows with content
    for(x = 1; x <= numRows; ++x){
      // Value of cell in loop
      var currentValue = dateRange.getCell(x,1).getValue();
      var adjacentCell = dateRange.getCell(x,2);
      Logger.log(currentValue);

      // If the date is less than or equal to today
      if(new Date(currentValue) <= new Date()){
        // Change adjancet cell to Expired
        adjacentCell.setValue("Expired");
        // Else adjance cell is Current
      } else if(currentValue != ""){
        adjacentCell.setValue("Current");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! The only thing I'm still a little worried about is the inclusion of all the empty cells. (Assuming there are to begin, only 5 rows of data) I'd like to prune empty cells from the range before running the date check loop.

Comment: I have updated my answer to exclude empty rows at the end of the sheet now.